# GcmBroadcastReceiver - GcmListenerService

Tags: google-cloud-messaging, broadcastreceiver

Could someone explain to me how the GCM receiver works in the following example. By setting at

```
gcm_receiver name = "com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmReceiver"
```

and in category my package what do I achieve? Does it mean that GCM messages are received from GCM receiver (without writing any code) and delivered to my app, where my GCM listener receives them?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="gcm.play.android.samples.com.gcmquickstart" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <!-- [START gcm_permission] -->
    <permission android:name="gcm.play.android.samples.com.gcmquickstart.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />
    <uses-permission android:name="gcm.play.android.samples.com.gcmquickstart.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
    <!-- [END gcm_permission] -->

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <!-- [START gcm_receiver] -->
        <receiver
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmReceiver"
            android:exported="true"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <category android:name="gcm.play.android.samples.com.gcmquickstart" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <!-- [END gcm_receiver] -->

        <!-- [START gcm_listener] -->
        <service
            android:name="gcm.play.android.samples.com.gcmquickstart.MyGcmListenerService"
            android:exported="false" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        <!-- [END gcm_listener] -->
        <!-- [START instanceId_listener] -->
        <service
            android:name="gcm.play.android.samples.com.gcmquickstart.MyInstanceIDListenerService"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        <!-- [END instanceId_listener] -->
        <service
            android:name=".RegistrationIntentService"
            android:exported="false">
        </service>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

From [com.google.android.gms.gcm](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/gcm/package-summary), GcmReceiver was described as `WakefulBroadcastReceiver` that receives GCM messages and delivers them to an application-specific `GcmListenerService` subclass.

Likewise, as also discussed in [Set up a GCM Client App on Android](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/client#top_of_page), in editing your application's Manifest:

- `GcmReceiver` handles messages sent from GCM to your application.
- `GcmListenerService` enables various aspects of handling messages such as detecting different downstream message types, determining upstream send status, and automatically displaying simple notifications on the app’s behalf.
- `InstanceIDListenerService` handles the creation, rotation, and updating of registration tokens.

Checking the documentation will help you to understand how GCM Client App works on Android.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I had checked the documentation before and checked it again. To my understanding, by adding GCMReceiver to my manifest and setting the category in intent filter to my package, what really happens is that, I tell the system that I can accept messages from GCMReceiver, only if they target my application (intent-filter).  Am I right? What I did not get was that it is possible to declare a receiver in manifest, without implementing it.